# Efficient way to make API requests without causing 429 error(too many requests)?

Tags: c#, .net, api, task

I have an API POST method that edits values in a single row of a table in the database. The API can take only 200 requests per minute or else it would throw 429. I have 35,000 rows that have to be written to the table from another table( So total 35,000 requests required).Rather than simply giving a delay before making each request (which I have done now), what would be the most efficient way(least amount of time) to do this?

```
 private static async void callMetadataAPI()
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        string strConnection = GetConnectionString("");
        string queryString = "select * from test.dbo.test_table";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage success = await runMetadataAPI(reader);
                    success.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionHandler(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        await Task.WhenAll();
        watch.Stop();

    }
    private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> runMetadataAPI(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test.com");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("JWT", "token");
        string requestUri = "/api/metadata";
        var metaDataPostData = new MetaDataPostData();
        metaDataPostData.CId= reader["CId"].ToString();
        metaDataPostData.SId = "somevalue"; 
        Metadata[] metaData = new Metadata[1];
        metaData[0] = new Metadata();
        metaData[0].Key = "columnname";
        metaData[0].Value = "columnvalue";
        metaDataPostData.Metadata = metaData;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(metaDataPostData);
        var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, data);
        return response;
    }
class MetaDataPostData
{
    public Metadata[] Metadata { get; set; }
    public string SId{ get; set; }

    public string CId { get; set; }

}
class Metadata
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

Given the API cannot be modified, any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Presently this code would take approximately 19 minutes to complete 1000 requests! and I am not sure if this is the right approach to do it for the whole data.

I prevent 429  in this code just by giving a delay `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` in the `runMetadataAPI` function (function that consumes the API).

Comment: If you can only write 200 rows per minute then there is nothing you can do with the info you provided.

Comment: @Charles oh..What else is required? My intention is to write 200 rows per minute, which I am not doing right now... I prevent 429 just by giving a delay `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` in the function that consumes the API..Thank you..:)

Comment: You do something like this: before the post `var start = DateTime.UtcNow`  
then after the post `var elapsed = (DateTime.UtcNow - start).TotalMilliseconds` `Sleep(1000 - elapsed)`

Comment: On a sidenote you should use a singleton for the Httpclient: https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/

Comment: @Gp_1993 a lot of api's with limits will return some sort of tracker in the response, usually in header values, letting you know how close you are to the limit or some sort of information like that. Have you checked the API you are usings documentation to see if they return any information like this? If they do, then you can put some simple logic in that reads this info and makes a call at appropriate times.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the requests per minute to be 200, then I would run your requests in batches and wait 1 minute between batches. You currently have your HttpClient recreated every request. You would want to create that in your class constructor and then re-use.
Something like this could work:

```
public class MyService() {
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyService() {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test.com");
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("JWT", "token");
    }

    private static async Task callMetadataAPI() 
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        var tasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();
        string strConnection = GetConnectionString("");
        string queryString = "select * from test.dbo.test_table";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {            
                var batchSize = 200;
                var currentIdx = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var batchFinished = currentIdx % batchSize == 0;
                    var metaDataTask = runMetadataAPI(reader, batchFinished);
                    tasks.Add(metaDataTask);
                    currentIdx++;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionHandler(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        watch.Stop();
    }

    private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> runMetadataApi(SqlDataReader reader, bool batchFinished) {
        if(batchFinished) {
            await Task.Delay(60000);
        }
        string requestUri = "/api/metadata";
        var metaDataPostData = new MetaDataPostData();
        metaDataPostData.CId= reader["CId"].ToString();
        metaDataPostData.SId = "somevalue"; 
        Metadata[] metaData = new Metadata[1];
        metaData[0] = new Metadata();
        metaData[0].Key = "columnname";
        metaData[0].Value = "columnvalue";
        metaDataPostData.Metadata = metaData;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(metaDataPostData);
        var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return client.PostAsync(requestUri, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: he wants to post as many as possible, so you should `Delay(60000 - elapsedMs)`

Comment: I understood that the API he is using was rate limiting his requests per minute to 200 which is why I suggested using batches.

Comment: if 200 posts take 30 seconds and you sleep 60 seconds after each batch you waste 30 seconds. Firing 200 async at the same time and then Delay might work, but its likely that he gets banned then for the little DDOS

Comment: I agree with that, however if there is an API constraint that does not allow more than 200 requests in a minute, then you will still get 429 responses for the rest of the 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response...@CameronTinker ...what is `ResultDto`? I didnt understand that..

Comment: @Gp_1993, that was a typo. It should just be a `Task`.